# TinyMCE - Image Source URL being changed to Relative, I need Absolute

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE, and I **think** I have the settings correct (as per the documentation in URL Handling) so that the URLs are handled as Absolute with Domain.

However, when I import some HTML (using another JavaScript) into the TinyMCE editor, or simply type a URL, it is always converted to a relative, which is no good when the content is then sent out as an email.

Here's the TinyMCE Initialisation Code:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea#messageBody',
    height: 500,
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: false,
    document_base_url: '[https://My-Domain/]',
    menubar: false,
    plugins: 'advlist autolink lists link image charmap preview anchor searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen insertdatetime media table code help wordcount',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | removeformat | link code help'
});
```

The document_base_url has my actual domain in there, with no square brackets... I've just put it like this in the post.
What's strange is that, if I click the CODE button in the TinyMCE editor, add the full URL back in manually and click SAVE, and then go back to check the CODE again, the full URL path to the image has again been replaced by the Relative path.

I've seen various posts on this, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Anyone have any thoughts/ideas?

Thanks very much.